# What are the products formed in acidic hydrolysis of a tetrahydropyranyl ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ethers

> Find the major product of the following reaction:
>
> [image]

**My  approach**

From my knowledge of reagents, I figured out that that the acid will protonate the oxygen(s) in the reactant and after that $\ce{C-O \sigma}$ bond should break, but I am not able to decide which $\ce{C-O}$ bonds to break in the reaction after protonation by the aqueous acid.

Am I thinking in the right direction or are there some other concepts involved?

Comment: The original compound is dihydropyran. This group is a tetrahydropyranyl ether and is widely used as an alcohol protecting group  https://www.organic-chemistry.org/protectivegroups/hydroxyl/thp-ethers.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The actual mechanism

Waylander has given an accurate reaction since this is a [THP ether](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/protectivegroups/hydroxyl/thp-ethers.htm)

[image]

The actual mechanism of the de-protection using alcoholysis would be as follows:

[image]

The actual mechanism of the de-protection using acidic hydrolysis would be as follows:

[image]

---

### A place to start from if you didn't know the mechanism

Seeing that the compound given resembles a carbonyl group that has been protected using ethylene glycol, a mechanism using a reaction similar to that of protection of carbonyl groups was used here to hypothesis what would happen(not knowing the original mechanism) and to decide the products formed.

> [image: protection of ketone]

Hence, taking a reversed approach here, the first question I ask is:

> **What could have formed this acetal in the first place?**

One part of the acetal seems to be connected to the carbonyl group and is part of the main molecule. The other side, however, is a different molecule. So, this is what the acetal formation looks like in the mechanism. Here, I assume $\ce{R}-$ is just an inert part of the molecule and so is equivalent to $\ce{CH3-CH2}-$. This may not be the right mechanism but it would give us a good starting point.

Formation of the hemiacetal takes place as follows:

> [image]

Formation of acetal using propanol can happen as follows:

> [image]

Which is the THP ether in the question.

---

#### What are the final products?

Therefore, the products of acid catalysed hydrolysis of the acetal would be $\ce{R-CH2-OH}$ and 5-hydroxypentanal which exists in equilibrium with its cyclic form dominating in mildly acidic conditions.

> [image]

The hydrolysis of the hydroxyderivative of THP would happen as follows. Both alcohols will get protonated but protonating the oxygen in $\ce{-OH}$ results in the same molecule being regenerated.

> [image]

Therefore, the final products would give $\ce{R-CH2-OH}$ and a hydroxy derivative of THP.

However, if $\ce{HCl}$ or $\ce{NaHSO3}$ is used instead of a weak lewis acid, we see the dominating compound in the equilibrium being 5-hydroxypentanal as shown in [this paper here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00304948909356391):

> [...] As a result of the acid-catalyzed hydration of 1, the 2-hydroxytetrahydropyran (2) was formed primarily which equilibrated with its open chain form, the 5-hydroxypentanal (3). The acid-catalyst (conc. hydrochloric acid), however, promotes not only the addition of water to the C-C double bond of 1, but also that of the OH groups in 1 and 2, thus resulting in the protected compounds 2-(2-tetrahydropyranyloxy) tetrahydropyran 0, and 5-(2-tetrahydropyranyloxy)pentanal (4). The ratio of 4 + 5 to 1 + 2: depends on the amount of acid used.[...]
>
> [image]

#### Reference:

1. Peter Vinczer , Zoltan Juvancz , Lajos Novak & Csaba Szantay (1989) AN
   IMPROVED SYNTHESIS OF 5-HYDROXYPENTANAL, Organic Preparations and Procedures International: The New Journal for Organic Synthesis, 21:3, 344-346, DOI: 10.1080/00304948909356391

Comment: The THP ether is usually formed from dihydropyran which is regenerated when the group is removed.

Comment: @user55119 It is SN1 (the reaction takes place via alcholysis). I'll modify that.  It's the same mechanism as aditya's answer, with the nucleophilic attack on the other side. I couldn't manually draw it for a generic compound since chemdoodle doesn't support it( currently do not have access to anything else), so I added the closest one.

Comment: @safdar: Back in pre-history we used the Fieser triangle.   https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/z103772?lang=en&region=US
Alas, it has been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
5-hydroxypentan-1-al is the product.

Comment: That SN2 reaction is ugly as sin

Comment: Indeed, you made a bad shortcut here, as this C atom isn't nearly as electrophilic as the other one.

Comment: @Safdar  You are correct that under aq acid conditions the 5-hydroxypentanal is formed  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3,4-Dihydropyran

Comment: @Waylander however, according to [Greene's Protective Groups in Organic Synthesis, Fourth Edition](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9780470053485.ch2), it depends on the conditions as you said. Using TsOH/MeOH yields a hydroxy derivative as shown in my answer (there are 30+ conditions giving different reactions).

Comment: @PCK: If the distasteful SN2 mechanism in the last step were operative, you couldn't form RCH2OTHP in the first place from THP and RCH2OH/H+?

Comment: @Safdar: In your response to Waylander are you saying that TsOH/MeOH forms tetrahydro-2H-pyran-2-ol and not 2-methoxytetrahydro-2H-pyran?

Comment: @user55119 It was an error on my part, I meant acid catalysed hydrolysis instead of TsOH/MeOH